# how to handle error not enough values to unpack in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, error-handling, action

In the following code user will enter single integer `N` as number of pairs that he should enter next as `b`. Assume the entered list is `b=[('r', 1),('a', 1),('a', 2),('a', 1),('r', 1),('r', 2)]` and the output should be B=[1].User will input data like below:

```
6
r 1
a 1
a 2
a 1
r 1
r 2
```

The code raised with error: 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)'

```
N = int(input())
B=[]
for i in range(N):
    b = (input().split())
for (action, value) in b:
  if action == 'a':
    B.append(value)
  elif action == 'r':
    try:
      B.remove(value)
    except ValueError:
      pass
```

Comment: Does the user input just the integer, or the letter and the integer?

Comment: you do understand that actually `b` is overwritten N number of times and you will not get N number of pairs, do you?

Comment: Letter and integer exactly like above.

Comment: `str.split()` default separator is any whitespace, so the result will depend on how exactly user is entering char and number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create the list you should append the user input as a tuple into the list 'b' first and then loop through it and handle the actions like so:

```
N = int(input())
B=[]
b = []
for i in range(N):
    user_input = input().split() # this returns a list
    b.append(tuple(user_input)) # append user input as a tuple

# Handle actions here
for (action, value) in b:
  if action == 'a':
    B.append(value)
  elif action == 'r':
    try:
      B.remove(value)
    except ValueError:
      pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over an array of values, unpacking each item into multiple variables. To do so, you need to have a 2D array (first dimension for looping over the array, second dimension to unpack the values).

You are trying to loop over the last value entered by user. In your case, it's `r 2` which is split to `['r', '2']`. In first iteration, you are trying to unpack `'r'` into 2 variables, which cannot be done.

Instead, you should just unpack the values as user inputs them.

```
N = int(input())
B=[]
for i in range(N):
  b = (input().split())
  action, value = b
  if action == 'a':
    B.append(value)
  elif action == 'r':
    try:
      B.remove(value)
    except ValueError:
      pass
```

Or use an array to store the inputs:

```
N = int(input())
B=[]

inputs = []
for i in range(N):
  b = (input().split())
  inputs.append(b)

for action, value in inputs:
  if action == 'a':
    B.append(value)
  elif action == 'r':
    try:
      B.remove(value)
    except ValueError:
      pass
```